# A phpbb3 user group to prevent posting

Tags: phpbb

I'm trying to prevent certain users from posting anywhere on the forum (as a penalty measure) and I thought to create a new group for it. 
What I did so far was create a new group and set permissions for a certain forum section to "Read only".

But when I test permissions by adding a user into the group and obtain his permissions I can still see the "Post new topic" button.

I also don't know how to maintain user's access level to certain sections (not all members have access to all sections) but prevent posting everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set permissions to `Never` for it to work.